# How to deal with asynchronous function and computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I am aware of the fact that computed properties do not support asynchronous function. But in my way asynchronous way is inevitable. What should be an alternative of doing it in almost same way I'm approaching to?

This is what I tried:

```
computed: {
        async filteredItems(){
            let term = this.store.searchTerm;
            this.newItems = await Products.searchProducts(term);
            console.log(this.newItems)
            return this.newItems;
        }
}
```

My `HTML` code with filtering items:

```
                        <div class="col-sm-4" v-for="item in filteredItems" :key=item.id>
                            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="single-products">
                                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                            <img :src="item.img" alt="" />
                                            <h2>{{item.price}} kn</h2>
                                            <p>{{item.title}}</p>
                                            <router-link to="/cart" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</router-link>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: is this vue2 or vue3 - it's important

Comment: It's a vue3 version.

Comment: so `this.store.searchTerm` is a promise and `Products.searchProducts(term)` returns a promise?

Comment: Keep a computed and side effects separated. Products.searchProducts should be used in a watcher

Comment: @JaromandaX actually just ```Products.searchProducts(term)```returns a promise

Comment: so why are you `await`ing `this.store.searchTerm` ... but Estus' comment is the way to tackle this

Comment: Apologies... my mistake, I fixed it in a question. I'll give it a try with ```watch```

Comment: @EstusFlask could you show how to use this in my case with ```watch```? I've never used it and I'm new with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of watch and data you don't even have to use computed, computed is mostly used to determine the value based on other props and data, which gets redetermined when these change.

```
data(): {
  return {
    searchTerm: this.store.searchTerm,
    filteredItems: [],
  }
},
watch: {
  async searchTerm() {
    this.filteredItems = await Products.searchProducts(term);
  }
},
```

ps: not sure if watch functions can be async, if not you can call a normal method to update the filteredItems.

Comment: This doesn't work for me... function ```searchTerm()``` is not even called. I think that it works in asynchronous way.